# Is it possible to pass arguments to a python script executed by GDB via `source`?

Tags: python, gdb

For example, I am using subprocess to run GDB and execute a python script:

```
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        f"gdb -p {pid} -ex 'source {command_file}'",
        shell=True,
    )
```

And the python script has something like:

```
import gdb

class MyBreakpoint (gdb.Breakpoint):
      def stop (self):
          inf_val = gdb.parse_and_eval("foo")
          if inf_val == 3:
              return True
          return False

MyBreakpoint("breakpoint_here")
```

Can I define "breakpoint_here" outside of this script, and pass it in as an argument? That way I can have the breakpoint determined in the first script (that launches GDB), either by command line argument or some other means, and use it in the sourced script.

So far I have tried setting GDB variables in the subprocess (via `set`), but when the sourced script is run those variables are not in scope.

Comment: gdb can be passed command to execute at start with switch -x, did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what the difference between running -x {command file} and -ex 'source {command file}' is, they both seem to run the same. How would I pass in a argument using -x? If I use --args an executable is expected, but in this case I have no executable to run since I am already attached to the running PID.

Comment: can't you write directly to the standard input of gdb via python?

Comment: `set` works for me. Try this: put `import gdb; print(gdb.parse_and_eval("$breakpoint_here"))` into `x.py`. Then type `gdb -q -ex='set $breakpoint_here="main.c:10"' -x x.py`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that is it! I did not realize I needed the parse_and_eval in order to access the variable set. Thank you so much!